# How to interpolate a map value with string in Less

Tags: css, less

I can't seem to get my LESS mapping logic to work. I have followed the [documentation](http://lesscss.org/features/#maps-feature) on mapping.

```css
@screen-size-min: {
  mobile-small: 320px;
  mobile-large: 480px;
  tablet-small: 600px;
  tablet-large: 768px;
  desktop-small: 992px;
  desktop-large: 1280px;
}

@min: min-width;

@desktop-small-min: ~"only screen and (@{min}: @screen-size-min[desktop-small])";

p {
  color: blue;

  @media @desktop-small-min {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I'm expecting this code to compile to css, but the media query does not seem to compile.

```css
p {
  color: blue;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  p {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

I tried testing it on [lesstester](https://lesstester.com/) but it only supports LESS 2.7 at this time. Maps is a new feature in LESS 3.5

There are no compile errors. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because `key[value]` is not actually a variable, the variable is the map `@screen-size-min`, therefore you can not take advantage of variable interpolation. One solution is to simply concat the KVP with the rest of the string:

```
@desktop-small-min: ~"only screen and (@{min}:" @screen-size-min[desktop-small] ~ ")";
```

This eliminates any dependency on creating *another* variable just to interpolate it

Additionally, per their documentation, maps were introduced:

> Released v3.5.0

And the online tester you tested with only supports **2.7**

Codepen usually supports their latest versions. Here's an anonymous pen demonstrating:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zeXmev

If you click on the little down arrow next to the 'CSS (Less)' header, you can select 'View Compiled CSS' and it will show you the LESS `->` CSS output

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and solution.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be working:

```
@screen-size-min: {
  mobile-small: 320px;
  mobile-large: 480px;
  tablet-small: 600px;
  tablet-large: 768px;
  desktop-small: 992px;
  desktop-large: 1280px;
}

@min: min-width;
@mysize: @screen-size-min[desktop-small];

@desktop-small-min: ~"only screen and (@{min}: @{mysize})";

p {
  color: blue;

  @media @desktop-small-min {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

It produces the desired result. Try it [here](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/)

Comment: Yes it works! Not sure why it needs to be variable interpolated but good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @soulshined , the problem is that I don't understand this myself - I just found by chance that this works in this case.